# Removing duplicate words from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say, we have some array like

```
[
"red book",
"red apple",
"socks",
"grey socks",
"red sky",
"red cross" <----- 4th "red", need to remove this element
"green cross",
"blue jeans"
]
```

So I need to delete, any array element that contains word repeating more than 3 times in the whole array. So, result for the example above might look like:

```
[
"red book",
"red apple",
"socks",
"grey socks",
"red sky",
 "green cross",
"blue jeans"
]
```

So the word "red" repeated more than 3 times in array. We have to keep up to 3 occurence of any word in array and delete other occurences' elements.

In my opinion, imploding whole array first with space symbol, then exploding into single words. And using `array_count` might lead to the result. But I can't finish this idea going this way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not to add yout php code? what have you been trying?

Comment: Is the match based only on the first word of an entry? For example, would "simple red" be considered a duplicate?

Comment: @alanlittle all words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write a function like this one:

```
function fix_array ($array)
{
    $filtered = array();
    $word_counts = array();

    foreach ($array as $i => $value)
    {
        $words = explode(' ', $value);
        $temp_word_counts = $word_counts;

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            if (array_key_exists($word, $temp_word_counts)){
                if ($temp_word_counts[$word] == 3){
                    continue 2;
                }
            }
            else{
                 $temp_word_counts[$word] = 0;
            }

            $temp_word_counts[$word]++;
        }

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            if (!array_key_exists($word, $word_counts)){
                $word_counts[$word] = 0;
            }
            $word_counts[$word]++;
        }

        $filtered[] = $value;
    }

    return $filtered;
}

$old_array = [
    "red book",
    "red apple",
    "socks",
    "grey socks",
    "red sky",
    "red cross",
    "green cross",
    "blue jeans"
];

$new_array = fix_array($old_array);
```

Comment: It would be nicer to the questioner if you provided a working script complete with inputs a call to your function, but as it works +1

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
   $arr = array(
        "red book",
        "red apple",
        "socks",
        "grey socks",
        "red sky",
        "red cross",
        "green cross",
        "blue jeans"
    );
    $used_words = array();
    $new_arr = array();

    array_walk($arr, function($val) {
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all('/\b\w+?\b/', $val, $matches);

        foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
            isset($GLOBALS['used_words'][$value]) ? $GLOBALS['used_words'][$value] += 1 : $GLOBALS['used_words'][$value] = 1;

            if ($GLOBALS['used_words'][$value] > 3) {
                return;
            }
        }

        $GLOBALS['new_arr'][] = $val;
    });

    print_r($new_arr);
```